# PHP Curl returning empty string on browser, working in postman

Tags: php, xml, curl, text, postman

I have some Php Curl code which was configured by Postman, my API SOAP call works perfectly on Postman but moving it into the browser I am getting back an empty string

I have tested changing the TEXT/XML to JSON as I have a similar call working 100% in JSON/APPLICATION as well as multiple languages but all seem to be returning an empty string.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/webservice.cfc?Wsdl=",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:hs=\"https://example.com/webservice.cfc?Wsdl\">\n    <soapenv:Body>\n        <hs:examplecall>\n            <hs:ws_username>xxx</hs:ws_username>\n            <hs:ws_password>xxx</hs:ws_password>\n            <hs:exampleparam>xxx</hs:exampleparam>\n        </hs:examplecall>\n    </soapenv:Body>\n</soapenv:Envelope>",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: text/xml",
    "Postman-Token: xxx",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-length: 445",
    "cookie: CFID=xxx; CFTOKEN=xxx"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

postman returns me exactly what I am looking for but the above code generated by postman is returning an empty string with no errors so I have nothing to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working and returning the way I want it to - the problem was the format of the XML was not in line with the WSDL file. I am not sure why but postman also added an = sign at the end of the WSDL and the format of the XML was different - here is the code used to get it working:

```
<?php

$xml_data = '
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hs="https://example.com/webservice.cfc?Wsdl">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <hs:exampleCall>
            <hs:ws_username>UN</hs:ws_username>
            <hs:ws_password>PW</hs:ws_password>
            <hs:exampleParam>xxx</hs:exampleParam>
        </hs:exampleCall>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/webservice.cfc?Wsdl",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xml_data,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Postman-Token: xxx",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: ;",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  print_r($response);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is SOAP call. You may want to try something like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://example.com/webservice.cfc?Wsdl');

$response = $client->examplecall(
        [
            'ws_username' => 'some_username',
            'ws_password' => 'some_pass',
            'exampleparam' => 'some_param'
        ]
);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, will test this out and let you know soon the outcome

Comment: Hi Honza, I have tested the call and definitely getting a response rather than the CURL approach which was returning nothing - just getting an invalid UN and PW combination which is strange as it works perfectly in postman, going to run a few more tests and see if I can nail down the error and will revert with the steps I took and accept your answer - Thanks again!